# how can i set the text of a textbox to a c++ code

Tags: c#, textbox

i want to set the text of a textbox to a c++ code on button click.

i've tried using

```
textBox1.Text = "c++ code here";
```

but it gives errors because the code is in c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623866/how-to-set-the-text-in-a-textbox-control-from-native-code

Comment: "it give all sort of errors because it reconizes them as funtions etc." is completely unhelpful. If you want us to explain what an error means, we have to see the error you actually got.

Comment: C# and C are completely different languages. Which one are you using? Only one of those tags belongs.

Comment: i am using c#, but i am creating a code generator, and what im basiclly trying to do is have it so that when the button is pressed the text box generates the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually escape characters like ".

```
TextBox1.Text = "some code here \"test\" hello...";
```